# select series from transposed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

With a dataframe, called `mrna` as follows:

```
id      Cell_1  Cell_2  Cell_3
CDH3    8.006   5.183   10.144
ERBB2   9.799   12.355  8.571
...
```

How can I select the ERBB2 row as a pandas series (if I don't know its index)?

I tried:
`mrna.iloc['ERBB2']` but that only takes a integer, and doesn't map to string

I also tried:

```
mrna_t = mrna.transpose()
mrna_t['ERBB2']
```

but I get KeyError: 'ERBB2'

Answer (score 2):

Pass a boolean condition to generate a boolean mask, this mask is used against the index and will return just the rows where the condition is met:

```
In [116]:
df[df['id']=='ERBB2']

Out[116]:
      id  Cell_1  Cell_2  Cell_3
1  ERBB2   9.799  12.355   8.571
```

Output from boolean condition:

```
In [117]:
df['id']=='ERBB2'

Out[117]:
0    False
1     True
Name: id, dtype: bool
```

As for your error: `mrna_t['ERBB2']` will attempt to look for a column with that name which doesn't exist hence the `KeyError`

If it was your index then you could just do:

```
df.loc['ERBB2']
```

To select index values matching the passed label, it's worth checking the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), including the section on [index selection by position and label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)

Comment: Thanks, I realized soon after that the transpose method didn't also transpose the indices.  Now everything is good.  Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.  I just reset the index labels then transposed.  This allowed me to index by "ERBB2".

`mrna.set_index('id').T`